# What was the standard pistol used in Yugoslavia during WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, weapons, yugoslavia

I've looked into the firearms used during WWII, but I can't find what pistol was used by Yugoslavian infantry men at the time. What did they use?

Comment: Maybe they only had a rifle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume it would have been the [F.N. model. 1922](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FN_Model_1910):

[image]

This was a variation of the F.N. model. 1910 that was commissioned by the Yugoslavian military in the inter-war period with 60,000 ordered with both general issue and "officer" markings.

Note, the Wikipedia article is horribly referenced, but you should be able to confirm this in  Anthony Vanderlinden's book *[FN Browning Pistols: Side-Arms That Shaped World History](http://books.google.com/books/about/FN_Browning_Pistols.html?id=7GpvQgAACAAJ)* as several other sites refer to it (I don't have a copy so can't verify this).

Answer (score 1):

This pistol had specific Cyrillic alphabet marking for the army, Latin alphabet marking for Police - "Policijski", Officer marking - "Oficirski" Etc. and specific name:

"Vojno-Drzavni pistolj" - "Military-State pistol"

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/FN_Model_1922_1653.jpg
http://sh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browning_1910/22_Vojno-dr%C5%BEavni

Comment: What makes you say this was the standard pistol?

Comment: Isn't that the same pistol as the accepted answer?

Comment: No, pistol  barrel was longer than original model (114 mm for Vojno-Drzavni pistol)  for the sake of greater accuracy, and magazine could accommodate 9 bullets, and other small minor things were changed.